# Call Oracle procedure with list of Java object as in parameter from spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, plsql, spring-data-jpa

So we have a requirement where we need to call Oracle stored procedure by passing a custom list of Java object as in parameter using spring boot, I did some research and couldn't get a proper implementation of it, beginner at spring boot so any help and reference implementation would help a lot.

What we need to do is to create a microservice that would fetch some records from mongo dB transform and then load to Oracle dB, but the call would be to a Oracle stored procedure, we were able to do all the mongo part and Oracle connection and calling Oracle stored procedure with a simple in parameter, but our requirement is to call this stored procedure by passing a list of Java object type. That is where we are stuck

Comment: Spring Boot is an open source Java-based framework mainly used to create  micro Services. Your question need more details. You can read more about Spring Boot here. https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

Comment: I am not sure what info I am missing, but what we need to do is to create a microservice that would fetch some records from mongo dB transform and then load to Oracle dB, but the call would be to a Oracle stored procedure, we were able to do all the mongo part and Oracle connection and calling Oracle stored procedure with a simple in parameter, but our requirement is to call this stored procedure by passing a list of Java object type. That is where we are stuck

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a database Config  bean class where u can store all the database(Oracle) related properties

**DatabaseConfigClass**

```
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {
  private static final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(DataBaseConfig.class);
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;
  @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
  public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws SQLException {
  OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();

  String url = environment.getProperty("spring.db.jdbc.url");
  String userName = environment.getProperty("spring.db.username");
  String password = environment.getProperty("spring.db.password");
  String driver = environment.getProperty("spring.db.driver-classname");

  dataSource.setUser(userName);
  dataSource.setPassword(password);
  dataSource.setURL(url);
  dataSource.setDriverType(driver);
  return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
 }
```

2) There are many ways to call a stored procedure. One of the best ways is using simple jdbc call

**ServiceClass**

```
public class getOrders(ApprovalAction approvalActionObj){

  List<Orders> orderList= approvalActionObj.getApprovalQsType();

  SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new 
  SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("XX_PROCEDURE")
 .withCatalogName("XX_PACKAGE").withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
 .declareParameters(
  new SqlParameter("P_ORDER_ROLLUP", Types.ARRAY,"ALG_ORDER_TAB"),
  new SqlOutParameter("O_ERROR_MESSAGE", Types.NUMBER));


  Object[][] orderArray = new Object[ordersList.size()][2];   

  for(int actionIndex = 0; actionIndex < ordersList.size(); actionIndex++) 
  {

  ordersArray[actionIndex][0] = orderList.get(actionIndex).getId();
  ordersArray[actionIndex][1] = orderList.get(actionIndex).getType();
  }
  Map<String, Object> orderResult=jdbcCall.execute(new 
  MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("P_ORDER_ROLLUP", new 
  SqlArrayValue(orderArray)));

  Integer errorMsg = (String) orderResult.get("O_ERROR_MESSAGE"); 
  }
```

**Note:** In your case you can pass all the custom objects as an Array.